# What is wrong with my anchors?

Tags: swift

I have got this anchors in my Swift code

```
    tableView.anchor(PostsDiv.bottomAnchor, left:view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 40, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant:0,heightConstant:tableView.contentSize.height+tableView.contentInset.bottom+tableView.contentInset.top) 
    ProfilePicture.anchor(cell.topAnchor, left:cell.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 15, leftConstant: 14, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 50,heightConstant:50)
    username.anchor(cell.topAnchor, left:ProfilePicture.rightAnchor, bottom: postText.topAnchor, right: cell.rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 13, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
    postText.anchor(nil, left:ProfilePicture.rightAnchor, bottom:border.topAnchor, right: cell.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 20, rightConstant: 0)
    border.anchor(nil, left:cell.leftAnchor, bottom: cell.bottomAnchor, right: cell.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 20, rightConstant: 0,heightConstant:1)
```

But i get this error that my constraints are wrong and this
`

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000286540 V:|-(20)-[UILabel:0x7f941ac2a200'theChampagnepapi']   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCell:0x7f941b016600 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080002865e0 UILabel:0x7f941ac2a200'theChampagnepapi'.bottom == UITextView:0x7f941b0b2800'He is right'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000286720 UITextView:0x7f941b0b2800'He is right'.bottom == UIView:0x7f941ac2b190.top - 20   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000286860 UIView:0x7f941ac2b190.bottom == UITableViewCell:0x7f941b016600.bottom - 20   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000286b80 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCell:0x7f941b016600.height == 44   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000286860 UIView:0x7f941ac2b190.bottom == UITableViewCell:0x7f941b016600.bottom - 20   (active)>
```

What is wrong with my constraints?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` (which you didn't set, but rather the table view did). So, two things:

1. Specify [`UITableViewAutomaticDimension`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewautomaticdimension) in `viewDidLoad` to ensure that the table's rows can be resized according to the constraints within the cell:

   ```
   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   ```
2. I find that if the constraints are such that the height of rows may differ, I sometimes have to reduce the `priority` of one of my vertical constraints to less than 1000. Even 999 is sufficient. And I generally do this to just one of the constraints (e.g. the bottom constraint).

Comment: I had the first one from begging like this `
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        return 55
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }`

Comment: I'd suggest removing those delegates and set these two properties at the table view level in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I did but unfortunately it still returns the same result

Comment: I added `tableView`'s contraints can you check that please?

Comment: And my second point about lowering the priority of one of the vertical constraints?